# Django HTML template not rendering content

Tags: django

I am building an notifcation system. I am almost complete the notifcation system. Now my problem is notifcation content not rendering my html template. I am not understanding where I am doing mistake.here is my code:

**notifications models.py:**

```
class Notifications(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey('blog.Blog',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    NOTIFICATION_TYPES = (('New Comment','New Comment'),('Comment Approved','Comment Approved'), ('Comment Rejected','Comment Rejected'))
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="noti_from_user")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="noti_to_user")
    notification_type = models.CharField(choices=NOTIFICATION_TYPES,max_length=250)
    text_preview = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_seen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**views.py**

```
def ShowNOtifications(request):
    user = request.user
    notifications = Notifications.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-date')
    Notifications.objects.filter(user=user, is_seen=False).update(is_seen=True)
    template_name ='blog/notifications.html'
     
   

    context = {
        'notify': notifications,
    }
          
    return render(request,template_name,context)
```

**#html**

```
{% for notification in notifications %} 
{% if notification.notification_type == "New Comment" %}

@{{ notification.sender.username }}You have received new commnet 
      <p>{{ notification.text_preview }}</p>
{%endif%}
{%endfor%}
```

why notification content not showing in my html template? where I am doing mistake?

Comment: it's not the cause of problem

Comment: It will not work. I tried

Comment: ahmad_fauzan458  your solution was wrong. it's different scenario

Comment: In your context you declare `'notify'`, so in your template you need use `notify.sender.username` instead of `notification.sender.username`

Comment: I tried but didn't work

Comment: Edit your context `'notify': notifications,` to `'notifications': notifications,`

Comment: {{notify.sender}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template you want loop through `notifications` but Django template can't find `notifications` because you declare in your context with label `'notify'`

```
context = {
    'notify': notifications,
}
```

So in your `views.py`, you can change `'notify'` to `'notifications'`:

```
context = {
    'notifications': notifications,
}
```

You can see document [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Context)

Answer (score 1):

First thing you are doing wrong is using the value in dictionary to render in the template.
Rather use the key, so your code should be:

```
{% for notification in notify %} 
{% if notification.NOTIFICATION_TYPES == "New Comment" %}

@{{ notification.sender}}You have received new commnet 
      <p>{{ notification.text_preview }}</p>
{%endif%}
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: This is not the solution . I tried this before posting the question

Comment: Also the variable date in the class and order_by date in your views are not matching.

Comment: may be this is not solving the issue however this is one of the issue you must fix, else you will not be able to render the data in template.

Comment: You always use the keys from the context dictionary to render the data in templates and not values.

Comment: Rohit_VE see the commnet before post the answer. he said he tried this method before posting question

Comment: Farhan Ahmed well said

Comment: Farhan_Ahmed, Look man, it does not matter weather he has tried or not, whatever in the code he has mentioned that's  not correct, at least he will get something corrected. You never use values to render into the templates, you always use keys. so with my response at least he will get some of the things corrected, may be there are some other issues which needs debug.

Comment: @boyenec Then update the code snippet to be correct. your template variable and context key don't match. As Rohit says, this is the first change you need to make before moving on to any others. Please See the Stackoverflow Guide on [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: +1, this answer is correct. I think OP have some problem with his if statement. That's why the content not showing and he think this answer is incorrect.